# Error 1 The type or namespace name * could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, generics, enums, typeof

I am trying to make a helper function that return an enum name of any type of enum- working from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I have run into this error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'enumType' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

From this func:

```
public static string EnumNameToString<T>( T enumType , T enumActual)
{
   return Enum.GetName( typeof( enumType ), enumActual );
}
```

Erroring on this line:

```
return Enum.GetName( typeof( enumType ), enumActual );
```

I have had a quick search around but seem to only find that people renaming projects etc are getting this error rather than this seems to me using generics.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**:

```
enum eEnumType
{
    eEnum0,
    eEnum1,
    eEnum2
}
enum eEnumType2
{
    e_Enum0,
    e_Enum1,
    e_Enum2
}

eEnumType anEnum;
eEnumType2 anEnum2;

string exampleStr = EnumNameToString<string>( eEnumType, eEnum0 );
string exampleStr2 = EnumNameToString<string>( eEnumType2, e_Enum2 );
```

Expect exampleStr to be "eEnum0".
Expect exampleStr2 to be "e_Enum2".

(New to generics so this could still be quite off, but hopefully gives insight to what I'm attempting to achieve).

Thanks again.

Comment: Your function do what it is not clear from definitIon can you show sample usage of this method

Comment: `typeof` wants a Type but your giving it a variable (`T` is a type)

Comment: I want to bable to pass in an enum type i.e. have many enums types but use this function universally... Is this possible?

Comment: Just replace typeof(enumType) for typeof(T) and it will compile

Comment: Is what you want  not the same as `eEnumType.eEnum0.ToString()`? `eEnum0` on its own is not valid, if the value is in a variable you would use    `Parse()` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703180/generic-method-enum-to-string-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Machinarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528131/machinarius) (**EDIT**: and [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k)) I made it work from your answer... Was getting confused with the generics.

Answer:

```
public static string EnumNameToString<T>(T enumActual)
{
     return Enum.GetName( typeof( T ), enumActual );
}
```

Used like:

```
string str = Helper.EnumNameToString<eEnumType>( eEnumType.eEnum0 );
```

Works perfectly. Thanks- a grateful nub!